# Kendo Grid get full url on update

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to get full request url on read (url + built-in paging/sorting + data) so to be able to update my browser history.

[image]

I cannot find any built-in functionality in the grid but I am looking for nice solution to achieve it instead to iterating by my own the data and append it. Maybe any function in the library to do that?

Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

This could help you :

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");    
var options = grid.getOptions();
console.log(options);
```

you can find filter and sorting related stuff within object.

Comment: Do you know a way is it possible to get directly the url used for read if I put my logic in requestEnd event? There I have access to e.sender.transport.options.read but wants to retrieve the url in ready for use format?

Comment: this.transport.options.read.url   : this => transport => options => Read => Url

Comment: This returns the which is specified in grid definition. I want to get ready for use URL + sort/page-params+data
example: myurl.com/testcontroller/testmethod?sortOrder=asc&page=0&pageSize=20&username=iv&status=RM&....